# net-ssh 3.0.1 required but not referenced

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh, rubygems

Really odd issue I'm having trying to run a rails app.

Upon running `bundle install` I'm thrown an error regarding `net-ssh`:

`` Gem::InstallError: net-ssh requires Ruby version >= 2.0.
An error occurred while installing net-ssh (3.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install net-ssh -v '3.0.1'` succeeds before bundling. ``

But no where in my app do we require `net-ssh -v '3.0.1'`. I'm running ruby v. `1.9.3-p429.

Below are the gem and Gemfile, Gemfile.lock files. Any guidance would be appreciated.

### Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '~>3.2.12'
gem "acts_as_paranoid", "~>0.4.0"
gem 'memcache-client'
gem 'tumblr_client'
# Page scraper
gem "httparty", "~>0.8"
gem "nokogiri", "~>1.5"
gem "mechanize"
gem "capybara"
gem "capybara-webkit", "~>1.0.0"
gem "headless"
# gem 'tesseract-ocr', :git => "git@github.com:CollegeAbacus/custom-ruby-tesseract-ocr.git", :branch => 'master'
gem 'rmagick', require: false

gem 'poltergeist'
# for the NCES NPC calculator demo
# gem "sinatra", "~>1.3"
# gem "shotgun", "~>0.9"
# gem "redis", "~>2.2"
# we don't use these anymore

# for the web application
gem 'pg'       # used in development and production
gem 'haml', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'sunspot_rails'
gem 'sunspot_solr'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'uniquify', :git => "git://github.com/teohm/uniquify.git"
gem 'acts_as_list', github: 'swanandp/acts_as_list'
gem 'select2-rails'
gem 'awesome_print'
gem "paper_trail", "~> 2.7.2", require: false #to track changes to models
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'
gem 'codemirror-rails'
gem 'devise_security_extension'
gem 'rails_email_validator'
gem "galetahub-simple_captcha", :require => "simple_captcha"
gem 'safe_yaml', '~> 0.8.6'
gem 'i18n-js'
gem 'bluecloth'
gem 'csv-mapper', require: false
gem "excel_functions", require: false
gem "enumerize"
gem 'hashie'
#gem 'inline_svg' #enable Nokogiri to parse SVG -- fmb

# for cron tasks
gem 'whenever', :require => false

# for rake tasks
gem 'progress_bar', :require => false

# Authentication
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.6'
gem 'rails_admin'


## loggly
gem 'syslogger', '~> 1.6.0'
gem 'lograge','~> 0.3.1'
# gem 'compass'
group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'  # I don't love coffeescript...
  gem 'compass-rails'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyracer' ,:platform => :ruby , :require => 'v8'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'zurb-foundation', '~> 4.0.0'
  gem 'bourbon'
  #gem 'turbo-sprockets-rails3', '~> 0.3.0' #causing issues (files with wrong params), and incompatibility (Rails admin)
end
# gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'

gem 'remotipart', '~> 1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'redis'
gem 'mailgun-rails'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'pry-rails'

# background jobs
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'daemons'
gem 'dj_mon'
gem 'acts_as_xlsx', require: false
# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# for manipulating AWS ec2 - used in /sas_blocks and the restart script
gem 'fog', require: false

# JS assets
gem 'gon'
gem 'rabl-rails'

# Use unicorn as the app server
gem 'unicorn'
#gem 'thin'

# Monitoring
gem 'newrelic_rpm' #, '~> 3.8.0' #at least 3.8 for unicorn

# mongo
# gem 'mongoid'

gem 'common_library', :git => "git@github.com:CollegeAbacus/abacus-common.git", :branch => 'master', require: false
gem 'useragent', '~> 0.15.2'
group :development do
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'active_record_query_trace'
  gem 'highline'
    gem 'annotate'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry', '~> 0.9.12'
  gem "launchy"

  #gem 'common_library', :path => 'common_library/'
  # gem 'debugger', '~> 1.6.8'
  gem 'foreman'
  gem 'minitest'
  # gem 'webmock'
  gem 'ruby-prof', require: false
  gem 'seed-fu'
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-minitest'
  gem 'rb-fsevent'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
  # gem "pry-debugger"
  gem "pry-doc"
  gem "pry-stack_explorer"
end

group :test do
  gem "database_cleaner"
  gem "simplecov", require: false
end

group :deploy, :development do
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 2.15.5', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-templates', require: false
  gem 'delayed_job', require: false # delayed/recipes
end
```

### Gemfile.lock

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list.git
  revision: e14d4fb12f1c9ff0574364ae7aefa23e4eba7939
  specs:
    acts_as_list (0.7.2)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/teohm/uniquify.git
  revision: d9675b7e1e89d1b2914ee43f33a973491b57bd00
  specs:
    uniquify (0.1.0)

GIT
  remote: git@github.com:CollegeAbacus/abacus-common.git
  revision: fc9695101eb09d77b97a67a4c14b95bec4f31841
  branch: master
  specs:
    common_library (0.0.77)
      acts_as_list
      httparty (~> 0.8)

GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    CFPropertyList (2.3.2)
    actionmailer (3.2.22)
      actionpack (= 3.2.22)
      mail (~> 2.5.4)
    actionpack (3.2.22)
      activemodel (= 3.2.22)
      activesupport (= 3.2.22)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.5)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    active_record_query_trace (1.5)
    activemodel (3.2.22)
      activesupport (= 3.2.22)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.22)
      activemodel (= 3.2.22)
      activesupport (= 3.2.22)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.22)
      activemodel (= 3.2.22)
      activesupport (= 3.2.22)
    activesupport (3.2.22)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    acts_as_paranoid (0.4.3)
      activerecord (~> 3.2)
    acts_as_xlsx (1.0.6)
      activerecord (>= 2.3.9)
      axlsx (>= 1.0.13)
      i18n (>= 0.4.1)
    addressable (2.3.8)
    annotate (2.6.10)
      activerecord (>= 3.2, <= 4.3)
      rake (~> 10.4)
    arel (3.0.3)
    awesome_print (1.6.1)
    axlsx (2.0.1)
      htmlentities (~> 4.3.1)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.1)
      rubyzip (~> 1.0.0)
    bcrypt (3.1.10)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    blockenspiel (0.4.5)
    bluecloth (2.2.0)
    bootstrap-sass (2.3.2.2)
      sass (~> 3.2)
    bourbon (4.2.6)
      sass (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.19)
    builder (3.0.4)
    capistrano (2.15.6)
      highline
      net-scp (>= 1.0.0)
      net-sftp (>= 2.0.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.0.14)
      net-ssh-gateway (>= 1.1.0)
    capistrano-helpers (0.11.1)
      capistrano (~> 2.0)
      git (~> 1.0)
      versionomy (~> 0)
    capistrano-shared-helpers (1.0.0)
    capistrano-ssh-helpers (1.0.0)
      capistrano
    capistrano-templates (1.0.0)
      capistrano
      capistrano-helpers
      capistrano-shared-helpers
      capistrano-ssh-helpers
      capistrano_colors
      captify
      rvm-capistrano
    capistrano_colors (0.5.5)
    captify (1.0.2)
      capistrano
    capybara (2.5.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    capybara-webkit (1.0.0)
      capybara (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.2)
      json
    chronic (0.10.2)
    chunky_png (1.3.4)
    cliver (0.3.2)
    codemirror-rails (5.6)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1)
    compass (1.0.3)
      chunky_png (~> 1.2)
      compass-core (~> 1.0.2)
      compass-import-once (~> 1.0.5)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
      sass (>= 3.3.13, < 3.5)
    compass-core (1.0.3)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      sass (>= 3.3.0, < 3.5)
    compass-import-once (1.0.5)
      sass (>= 3.2, < 3.5)
    compass-rails (2.0.5)
      compass (~> 1.0.0)
      sass-rails (< 5.1)
      sprockets (< 2.13)
    csv-mapper (0.5.1)
      fastercsv
    curb (0.8.8)
    daemons (1.2.3)
    database_cleaner (1.5.1)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    delayed_job (4.1.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
    delayed_job_active_record (4.1.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0, < 5)
      delayed_job (>= 3.0, < 5)
    devise (3.5.2)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      responders
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    devise_security_extension (0.9.2)
      devise (>= 2.0.0)
      rails (>= 3.1.1)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    dj_mon (1.1.0)
      haml (~> 3.1)
      rails (~> 3.1)
    docile (1.1.5)
    domain_name (0.5.25)
      unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
    enumerize (1.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.8)
    excel_functions (0.0.4)
    excon (0.45.4)
    execjs (2.6.0)
    factory_girl (4.5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.5.0)
      factory_girl (~> 4.5.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faraday (0.9.2)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    faraday_middleware (0.9.2)
      faraday (>= 0.7.4, < 0.10)
    fastercsv (1.5.5)
    ffi (1.9.10)
    fission (0.5.0)
      CFPropertyList (~> 2.2)
    fog (1.35.0)
      fog-aliyun
      fog-atmos
      fog-aws (>= 0.6.0)
      fog-brightbox (~> 0.4)
      fog-core (~> 1.32)
      fog-dynect (~> 0.0.2)
      fog-ecloud (~> 0.1)
      fog-google (>= 0.1.1)
      fog-json
      fog-local
      fog-powerdns (>= 0.1.1)
      fog-profitbricks
      fog-radosgw (>= 0.0.2)
      fog-riakcs
      fog-sakuracloud (>= 0.0.4)
      fog-serverlove
      fog-softlayer
      fog-storm_on_demand
      fog-terremark
      fog-vmfusion
      fog-voxel
      fog-xenserver
      fog-xml (~> 0.1.1)
      ipaddress (~> 0.5)
      nokogiri
    fog-aliyun (0.0.10)
      fog-core (~> 1.27)
      fog-json (~> 1.0)
      ipaddress (~> 0.8)
      xml-simple (~> 1.1)
    fog-atmos (0.1.0)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-aws (0.7.6)
      fog-core (~> 1.27)
      fog-json (~> 1.0)
      fog-xml (~> 0.1)
      ipaddress (~> 0.8)
    fog-brightbox (0.9.0)
      fog-core (~> 1.22)
      fog-json
      inflecto (~> 0.0.2)
    fog-core (1.32.1)
      builder
      excon (~> 0.45)
      formatador (~> 0.2)
      mime-types
      net-scp (~> 1.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.1.3)
    fog-dynect (0.0.2)
      fog-core
      fog-json
      fog-xml
    fog-ecloud (0.3.0)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-google (0.1.1)
      fog-core
      fog-json
      fog-xml
    fog-json (1.0.2)
      fog-core (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.10)
    fog-local (0.2.1)
      fog-core (~> 1.27)
    fog-powerdns (0.1.1)
      fog-core (~> 1.27)
      fog-json (~> 1.0)
      fog-xml (~> 0.1)
    fog-profitbricks (0.0.5)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
      nokogiri
    fog-radosgw (0.0.4)
      fog-core (>= 1.21.0)
      fog-json
      fog-xml (>= 0.0.1)
    fog-riakcs (0.1.0)
      fog-core
      fog-json
      fog-xml
    fog-sakuracloud (1.3.3)
      fog-core
      fog-json
    fog-serverlove (0.1.2)
      fog-core
      fog-json
    fog-softlayer (1.0.0)
      fog-core
      fog-json
    fog-storm_on_demand (0.1.1)
      fog-core
      fog-json
    fog-terremark (0.1.0)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-vmfusion (0.1.0)
      fission
      fog-core
    fog-voxel (0.1.0)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-xenserver (0.2.2)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-xml (0.1.2)
      fog-core
      nokogiri (~> 1.5, >= 1.5.11)
    font-awesome-sass-rails (3.0.2.2)
      railties (>= 3.1.1)
      sass-rails (>= 3.1.1)
    foreman (0.78.0)
      thor (~> 0.19.1)
    formatador (0.2.5)
    galetahub-simple_captcha (0.1.5)
    git (1.2.9.1)
    gon (6.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      json
      multi_json
      request_store (>= 1.0)
    guard (2.13.0)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (>= 2.7, <= 4.0)
      lumberjack (~> 1.0)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      notiffany (~> 0.0)
      pry (>= 0.9.12)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
      thor (>= 0.18.1)
    guard-compat (1.2.1)
    guard-minitest (2.4.4)
      guard-compat (~> 1.2)
      minitest (>= 3.0)
    haml (3.1.8)
    haml-rails (0.4)
      actionpack (>= 3.1, < 4.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.1, < 4.1)
      haml (>= 3.1, < 4.1)
      railties (>= 3.1, < 4.1)
    hashie (3.4.2)
    headless (2.2.0)
    highline (1.7.8)
    hike (1.2.3)
    htmlentities (4.3.4)
    http-cookie (1.0.2)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    httparty (0.13.7)
      json (~> 1.8)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    i18n-js (2.1.2)
      i18n
    inflecto (0.0.2)
    ipaddress (0.8.0)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (3.0.1)
      jquery-rails
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
    json (1.8.3)
    jwt (1.5.1)
    kaminari (0.16.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    kgio (2.10.0)
    launchy (2.4.3)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    libv8 (3.16.14.13)
    listen (3.0.3)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
    lograge (0.3.4)
      actionpack (>= 3)
      activesupport (>= 3)
      railties (>= 3)
    lumberjack (1.0.9)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mailgun-rails (0.1.1)
      actionmailer
      activesupport
      curb
    mechanize (2.7.2)
      domain_name (~> 0.5, >= 0.5.1)
      http-cookie (~> 1.0.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.17, >= 1.17.2)
      net-http-digest_auth (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.1)
      net-http-persistent (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.2)
      nokogiri (~> 1.4)
      ntlm-http (~> 0.1, >= 0.1.1)
      webrobots (>= 0.0.9, < 0.2)
    memcache-client (1.8.5)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    mini_portile (0.6.2)
    minitest (5.8.1)
    multi_json (1.11.2)
    multi_xml (0.5.5)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    nenv (0.2.0)
    nested_form (0.3.2)
    net-http-digest_auth (1.4)
    net-http-persistent (2.9.4)
    net-scp (1.2.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-sftp (2.1.2)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (3.0.1)
    net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    netrc (0.10.3)
    newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    notiffany (0.0.8)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
    ntlm-http (0.1.1)
    oauth (0.4.7)
    oauth2 (1.0.0)
      faraday (>= 0.8, < 0.10)
      jwt (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      multi_xml (~> 0.5)
      rack (~> 1.2)
    omniauth (1.2.2)
      hashie (>= 1.2, < 4)
      rack (~> 1.0)
    omniauth-facebook (2.0.1)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.2)
    omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.2.8)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
      jwt (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      omniauth (>= 1.1.1)
      omniauth-oauth2 (>= 1.1.1)
    omniauth-oauth (1.1.0)
      oauth
      omniauth (~> 1.0)
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.3.1)
      oauth2 (~> 1.0)
      omniauth (~> 1.2)
    omniauth-twitter (1.2.1)
      json (~> 1.3)
      omniauth-oauth (~> 1.1)
    options (2.3.2)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    paper_trail (2.7.2)
      activerecord (~> 3.0)
      railties (~> 3.0)
    pg (0.18.3)
    poltergeist (1.7.0)
      capybara (~> 2.1)
      cliver (~> 0.3.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.2.0)
    polyglot (0.3.5)
    pr_geohash (1.0.0)
    progress_bar (1.0.5)
      highline (~> 1.6)
      options (~> 2.3.0)
    pry (0.9.12.6)
      coderay (~> 1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    pry-doc (0.8.0)
      pry (~> 0.9)
      yard (~> 0.8)
    pry-rails (0.3.4)
      pry (>= 0.9.10)
    pry-stack_explorer (0.4.9.2)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7)
      pry (>= 0.9.11)
    quiet_assets (1.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
    rabl-rails (0.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.1)
      railties (>= 3.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3.1)
    rack (1.4.7)
    rack-cache (1.5.0)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-pjax (0.8.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)
      rack (~> 1.1)
    rack-ssl (1.3.4)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.22)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.22)
      actionpack (= 3.2.22)
      activerecord (= 3.2.22)
      activeresource (= 3.2.22)
      activesupport (= 3.2.22)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.22)
    rails3-jquery-autocomplete (1.0.15)
      rails (>= 3.2)
    rails_admin (0.4.4)
      bootstrap-sass (~> 2.2)
      builder (~> 3.0)
      coffee-rails (~> 3.1)
      font-awesome-sass-rails (~> 3.0, >= 3.0.0.1)
      haml (~> 3.1)
      jquery-rails (~> 2.1)
      jquery-ui-rails (~> 3.0)
      kaminari (~> 0.14)
      nested_form (~> 0.3)
      rack-pjax (~> 0.6)
      rails (~> 3.1)
      remotipart (~> 1.0)
      safe_yaml (~> 0.6)
      sass-rails (~> 3.1)
    rails_email_validator (0.1.4)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
    railties (3.2.22)
      actionpack (= 3.2.22)
      activesupport (= 3.2.22)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    raindrops (0.15.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.6)
    rb-inotify (0.9.5)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    redis (3.2.1)
    ref (2.0.0)
    remotipart (1.2.1)
    request_store (1.2.0)
    responders (1.1.2)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 4.2)
    rest-client (1.8.0)
      http-cookie (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3.0)
      netrc (~> 0.7)
    rmagick (2.15.4)
    rsolr (1.0.13)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
    rspec-core (3.3.2)
      rspec-support (~> 3.3.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.3.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.3.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.3.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.3.0)
    rspec-rails (3.3.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      rspec-core (~> 3.3.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.3.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.3.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.3.0)
    rspec-support (3.3.0)
    ruby-prof (0.15.8)
    rubyzip (1.0.0)
    rvm-capistrano (1.5.6)
      capistrano (~> 2.15.4)
    safe_yaml (0.8.6)
    sass (3.4.19)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    seed-fu (2.3.5)
      activerecord (>= 3.1, < 4.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.1, < 4.3)
    select2-rails (4.0.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    shellany (0.0.1)
    simple_form (2.1.3)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activemodel (~> 3.0)
    simple_oauth (0.3.1)
    simplecov (0.10.0)
      docile (~> 1.1.0)
      json (~> 1.8)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.10.0)
    simplecov-html (0.10.0)
    slop (3.6.0)
    sprockets (2.2.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sunspot (2.2.0)
      pr_geohash (~> 1.0)
      rsolr (~> 1.0.7)
    sunspot_rails (2.2.0)
      nokogiri
      rails (>= 3)
      sunspot (= 2.2.0)
    sunspot_solr (2.2.0)
    syslogger (1.6.4)
    therubyracer (0.12.2)
      libv8 (~> 3.16.14.0)
      ref
    thin (1.6.4)
      daemons (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.0)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tumblr_client (0.8.5)
      faraday (~> 0.9.0)
      faraday_middleware (~> 0.9.0)
      json
      mime-types
      oauth
      simple_oauth
    tzinfo (0.3.45)
    uglifier (2.7.2)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.7.1)
    unicorn (4.9.0)
      kgio (~> 2.6)
      rack
      raindrops (~> 0.7)
    useragent (0.15.2)
    versionomy (0.4.4)
      blockenspiel (>= 0.4.5)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    webrobots (0.1.1)
    websocket-driver (0.6.2)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
    whenever (0.9.4)
      chronic (>= 0.6.3)
    will_paginate (3.0.7)
    xml-simple (1.1.5)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)
    yard (0.8.7.6)
    zurb-foundation (4.0.9)
      sass (>= 3.2.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  active_record_query_trace
  acts_as_list!
  acts_as_paranoid (~> 0.4.0)
  acts_as_xlsx
  annotate
  awesome_print
  bluecloth
  bourbon
  capistrano (~> 2.15.5)
  capistrano-templates
  capybara
  capybara-webkit (~> 1.0.0)
  codemirror-rails
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  common_library!
  compass-rails
  csv-mapper
  daemons
  database_cleaner
  delayed_job
  delayed_job_active_record
  devise
  devise_security_extension
  dj_mon
  enumerize
  excel_functions
  factory_girl_rails
  fog
  foreman
  galetahub-simple_captcha
  gon
  guard
  guard-minitest
  haml (~> 3.1.7)
  haml-rails
  hashie
  headless
  highline
  httparty (~> 0.8)
  i18n-js
  jquery-rails
  launchy
  lograge (~> 0.3.1)
  mailgun-rails
  mechanize
  memcache-client
  minitest
  newrelic_rpm
  nokogiri (~> 1.5)
  omniauth
  omniauth-facebook
  omniauth-google-oauth2
  omniauth-twitter
  paper_trail (~> 2.7.2)
  pg
  poltergeist
  progress_bar
  pry (~> 0.9.12)
  pry-doc
  pry-rails
  pry-stack_explorer
  quiet_assets
  rabl-rails
  rails (~> 3.2.12)
  rails3-jquery-autocomplete
  rails_admin
  rails_email_validator
  rb-fsevent
  redis
  remotipart (~> 1.0)
  rest-client
  rmagick
  rspec-rails
  ruby-prof
  safe_yaml (~> 0.8.6)
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.6)
  seed-fu
  select2-rails
  simple_form
  simplecov
  sunspot_rails
  sunspot_solr
  syslogger (~> 1.6.0)
  therubyracer
  thin
  tumblr_client
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
  unicorn
  uniquify!
  useragent (~> 0.15.2)
  whenever
  will_paginate
  zurb-foundation (~> 4.0.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.10.6
```

Comment: Any reason why you don't just upgrade Ruby? Later versions of ruby are both faster and more secure. Also Ruby 1.9.3 met its End Of Life 2015/02/23 so it is no longer supported and security fixes are no longer provided.

Comment: And they error is probably due to one of gems requiring `net-ssh` (my guess is capistrano). You won't find it in the Gemfile.lock since it is generated when `gem update` succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

I change the version of net-ssh in Gemfile , and it worked well

```
group :test, :development do
  gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.5.0"
  gem 'factory_girl', '2.6.4'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.7.0'
  gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
  gem 'forgery', '0.5.0'
  gem 'magic_encoding', '0.0.2'
  gem 'email_spec', '1.4.0'

  gem 'net-ssh', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 2.15.7'
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '1.0.5'
  gem 'rb-readline','0.4.2'
end
```